# How to get values from grid using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on resume parser and i can get some of data i.e company details from text but not getting if it is kept in a grid or table

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

public class CmpnyNameex {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        String text="";
        String name="";
            XWPFDocument msDocx = new  XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("A:\\Resumes\\Anwesh.docx")); 
            XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(msDocx);
            text = extractor.getText();      
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){ex.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The system cannot find the      file specified file it may be because of old file    format","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        String rx13="(?<=Have been associated with).*.(.*Ltd?)";                
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(rx13);
        Matcher found1 = p1.matcher(text);          
        while(found1.find())
        {
            name= found1.group(0);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: so what value you wanna capture?

Comment: can you show us a simple input output ?